# How can I install AWN trunk?

Tags: 11.04, awn

I've been trying to install AWN trunk in Natty Ubuntu Classic Desktop,but after add the PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:awn-testing/ppa`.

Update the sources: `sudo apt-get update`.

And install the files:

`sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator-trunk avant-window-navigator-data-trunk python-awn-trunk awn-settings-trunk awn-applets-python-core-trunk python-awn-extras-trunk awn-applets-python-extras-trunk awn-applets-c-core-trunk awn-applets-c-extras-trunk`

I've got the following (My system is in spanish):

```
`Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho`                                            
`Creando árbol de dependencias       `
`Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho`  
`El paquete awn-applets-c-core-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente`

`El paquete awn-applets-python-core-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente`

`El paquete awn-applets-c-extras-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente`

`El paquete awn-applets-python-extras-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente`

`E: El paquete «awn-applets-python-core-trunk» no tiene un candidato para la instalación`   
`E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete python-awn-extras-trunk`  
`E: El paquete «awn-applets-python-extras-trunk» no tiene un candidato para la instalación`  
`E: El paquete «awn-applets-c-core-trunk» no tiene un candidato para la instalación`  
`E: El paquete «awn-applets-c-extras-trunk» no tiene un candidato para la instalación`
```

Am I doing someting wrong?, or there is no AWN trunk for Natty?.

Comment: to set the output in english put LANG=c begore your command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try just

```
sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator-trunk
```

that did the trick for me on natty just 5 secs ago. I think yours is just a typo problem :)

Answer (score -1):

First, Install [**Ubuntu Tweak**](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

Then you can install the necessary software, cleaning your system and configuring the many settings of Ubuntu.

Screenshot for Avant Window Navigator (Lang : Turkish)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/98axm.jpg